# TypeError: current.map is not a function - Trying to display json object

Tags: reactjs, next.js

I have fetched json data from API and am trying to display it. Am able to console log the array but have been unable to display in a div. Map() function does not work on this data.

React / Next.js app

Trying to display json object in div but getting TypeError on map() function.

```
const getCurrentData = async () => {
    const res = await fetch("http://api.weatherapi.com/v1/current.json?key=84703323c7f94238a98203306233010&q=London&aqi=no")
    return res.json();
};


export default async function Weather() {
    const current = await getCurrentData();
    return (
        <>
            {current.map((current: any, index) => {
                <div key="{index}">
                    <span>{current.location}</span>
                    <span>{current.humidity}</span>
                </div>
            })}
        </>
    );
}
```

Comment: I don't know react, but to me it looks simply as if you were trying to use an array method (".map" ) on an ordinary object. Your fetch-result is not the data for an array of locations, but the result object for a single location, for which you don't need a map at all, but simply could write `return (<><div key="{index}"><span>{current.location}</span><span>{current.current.humidity}</span></div></>);`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

React components can not be asynchronous functions. Instead they should be pure and isolate side effects.

Use useState to fetch data and use useState to then display it inside your application.

Edit: Here is an example

```html
const getCurrentData = async () => {
    const res = await fetch("http://api.weatherapi.com/v1/current.json?key=84703323c7f94238a98203306233010&q=London&aqi=no")
    return await res.json();
};


export default async function Weather() {
    const [data, setData] = useState();

    useEffect(() => {
      async function getCurrentData() {
        const res = await fetch("http://api.weatherapi.com/v1/current.json?key=84703323c7f94238a98203306233010&q=London&aqi=no")
        const dataObj = await res.json();
        setData(dataObj);
      }
      getCurrentData();
    }, [])
    return (
        <>
            {data.map((item, index) => {
                <div key="{index}">
                    <span>{item.location}</span>
                    <span>{item.humidity}</span>
                </div>
            })}
        </>
    );
}
```

Comment: I have refactored but still have an error:

Error: Objects are not valid as a React child....

Comment: I have edited my answer to include an example

Answer (score 0):

I have refactored but still have an error:

Error: Objects are not valid as a React child....

```
"use client"
import { useState, useEffect } from "react";

const App = () => {
    const [current, setCurrent] = useState("");

    useEffect(() => {
        const url = "http://api.weatherapi.com/v1/current.json?key=84703323c7f94238a98203306233010&q=London&aqi=no";

        const fetchData = async () => {
            try {
                const response = await fetch(url);
                const json = await response.json();
                console.log(json.current);
                setCurrent(json.current);
            } catch (error) {
                console.log("error", error);
            }
        };

        fetchData();
    }, []);

    return (
        <>
            <div>{current}</div>
        </>
    );
};

export default App;
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).